# About Designing a Database

Tags: xml, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a question about database designing.

Which one is better design for relatively big database system;

Design1
[image]

Design2
[image]

In my opinion I comfortable with the second one, but the first one is more traditional than the second one I guess.

What is your thoughts?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain how we are supposed to read the second diagram.

Comment: @philipxy I think the diagrams very clear. On first one we store the student phone numbers in another table, and on the second one we store the student phone numbers in same table with using XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. What if two students live in a dorm, and have (share) the same phone number (a dorm phone), or are siblings living at home? the phone number table should be a composite key with `phonenumber`, *and* `studentId` as composite Primary Key. This reflects what is called a *many-to-many*, or associative relationship, which cannot easily be represented in XML.

The below schema assumes that each student gets to determine the "type" of phone he/she uses that line for. if the type of phone is determined only by the phone, then you would add another, separate, table for the phonenumbers and phone types, without `studentId`, and make the `phoneNumber` field in the associative table a foreign key (FK) to that new phone table

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will cosider your correction. 
But, that's not the answer I'm looking to, what I want to learn is "Which approach is more useful, relations or XML?" 
Thank you again.

Comment: ahhhh, if that's all you're interested in then relational is the answer. You can't easily do many-to-many relationship in XML.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with Design 1, but with a modification. Phone number table, though, would have Student ID as the primary key. This way you can have more than one student use the same phone, which is a completely normal scenario to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll consider your warning.

Comment: If phone number table has `studentId` as Primary Key, then there can only be one record per student. No, there needs to be a COMPOSITE Primary Key, on `studentId` AND `phoneNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't overthink this by normalising the phone numbers out to some potentially infinite list.

How many/what type of phone numbers do you really need for a student? Do you need a fax number for them, for instance? *Maybe* you need a term time and a non-term time number?

It seems much more likely that you need a single primary number, and an alternate, and those can be stored in the student table itself.

Comment: Than you for your answer. But I noticed that all of you guys are obsessed my little student example, I designed this database just for "example" purposes. What I really want to learn is, using XML is a bad practice for designing databases.

Comment: @OnurEryilmaz We can only answer the question you asked, and characterising people who took time to help as being "obsessed" is quite rude. You should have asked: "Is using XML a bad practice for designing databases?", or better yet referred to any of the existing questions on the topic.

Comment: I'm sorry about my language, I didn't think of "obsessed" is rude.  But as I ask in my question "which desing" is better. I didn't ask "Is my first diagram is wrong?". But again I'm sorry.